# Rebuilding the xdb index in Solr 8.1.1 does not finish

Tags: solr, xdb, exm, list-manager, segmented-list

On `Sitecore 9.3` and `Solr 8.1.1` I am trying to rebuild the xdb index and have started monitoring it, the progress has been stuck at 55.74 % for more than 10 hours, however, I see xdb index is moving up (numDocs) slowly and the xdb_rebuild stopped moving up since then. We are talking about more than 38 million docs.
I see this recurrent error in the log file under the IndexWorker folder. At the same time, the segmented lists in Sitecore contain fewer contacts than they should have.
I opened a ticket on the sitecore support portal but I haven't got back from them.
I checked the shard databases and the contact tables contain similar number of records.
[Shard1], the total of records in the Contact table is: `983,760`
[Shard0], the total of records in the Contact table is: `982,254`

> An error occured during resuming a previous index rebuild process.
> There will be another attempt to check. The check interval after an
> error is 00:00:20. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
> status code does not indicate success: 413 (Request Entity Too Large).

It looks like something is getting some time to process, and maybe I’d need to change a setting value. I have not found anything regarding this error message in `Solr/Sitecore.`

Thoughts?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since the error message indicates a request entity that is too large, it may be worth reviewing your Solr configuration. Specifically, check the maximum request size allowed in Solr's configuration files, such as solrconfig.xml. Ensure that it is set to a value that can accommodate the size of your index rebuild process.